# Little Complex Mysql Update

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update using if which is shown below
you will get idea what i want to do

```
UPDATE messages SET IF(u1= :username,u1_delete=1,u2_delete=1) 
WHERE thread_id= :thread_id
```

i want update u1_delete when u1 is username otherwise it will update u2_delete field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the case statement as follows:

```
UPDATE messages 
SET 
    u1_delete = CASE WHEN u1= :username THEN 1 ELSE u1_delete END,
    u2_delete = CASE WHEN u1= :username THEN u2_delete ELSE 1 END,
WHERE 
    thread_id= :thread_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` in the update. The trick is to update `u1_delete` when `:username = u1` and otherwise set it to its current value so it doesn't become `NULL`, and do the same for `u2_delete` if `:username <> u1`, which covers the "else" case of your `IF()`.

```
UPDATE 
  message
SET
  u1_delete = CASE WHEN u1 = :username THEN 1 ELSE u1_delete END,
  u2_delete = CASE WHEN u1 <> :username THEN 1 ELSE u2_delete END,
WHERE thread_id = :thread_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE messages   
SET  
u1_delete = IF(u1 = :username, 1, u1_delete),  
u2_delete = IF(u1 <> :username, 1, u2_delete)  
WHERE thread_id= :thread_id;
```

So basically, if u1 = username, you're setting to u1_deleted = 1, otherwise u1_deleted is set to itself and doesn't change.
If u1 does not equal the username, then u2_delete = 1, otherwise u2_delete is set to itself and doesn't change.

Is this what you want?